# Conjuctive normal form of $(p\wedge(q\implies r))\implies s$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am asked to write this in CNF without using truth tables.

This is what I worked out so far:

$$(p\wedge(q\implies r))\implies s \\
\neg(p\wedge (q\implies r)) \vee s\\
(\neg p \vee \neg(\neg q \vee r))\vee s \\
\neg p \vee (q \wedge \neg r) \vee s
$$

How do I move on from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the distributive law to move the conjunctions above the disjunctions.

(But first fix the error in your rewriting so far -- it looks like $r$ should be $\neg r$).

Comment: Thank you first of all. I used the law and arrived here:
$(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r) \vee s$


What next?

Comment: @Panayiotis: Once again, to the right this time.

Comment: How? I have two disjunctions on the right, how can I use it?

Can't I just do $(\neg p \vee q) \wedge (\neg p \vee r \vee s) $ ?

Comment: @Panayiotis: You may be confused by the fact that you're missing some parentheses. What you should have is $((\neg p \lor q)\land(\neg p\lor \neg r))\lor s$. Distribute the $\land$ over the $\cdots\lor s$.